# What movie or show had pirates under a little girl's bed?

Tags: story-identification

I remember a movie/show clip when I was ~4-6 years old ~(1998-2000) that I've been wondering about for years, so of course it is pretty fuzzy, and I remember only a short clip of it. It was live action, a little girl (maybe in the 6-9 range) was being tucked into bed (all caucasian actors), she was mostly under the covers but I think she was wearing a nightgown. The camera mostly focused on the little girl, I don't remember her parent being shown, but she was scared to go to sleep because there was a pirate under her bed. The parent did not seem to care/didn't believe her and left her to go to sleep. There was a very unsettling and scary feeling about this.

Part of what I saw involved her leaving food out on a white plate for the pirate under her bed, which either a hand or a hook would come out and grab the plate, drag it under the bed, and then push it back out when finished with it. I think there were sounds of eating at this point that were ominous, and the camera was positioned top down to look at the plate as it slid in and out from under the bed. The plate was left on the floor near her nightstand (both her bed and nightstand were a brown-looking wooden material, a lot of the room was browns/dark tones). I think the little girl was leaving it for him there, but I cannot be sure. I think the pirate was barely shown, and might have had a bird or human companion, someone seemed to be with him. I get a Captain Hook-looking pirate vibe from this pirate, but darker than that cartoon could have shown (and this is not a cartoon). They definitely had a sinister look or feel. Oddly enough, I for some reason feel like she was trying to help them even though they were very scary.

After eating, I think he was complaining to his bird or companion about the situation of being trapped under her bed, maybe they were trying not to be discovered? They had gritty, mean voices. I got the feeling that under the bed led to an entirely different place, or that somehow there were a large number of pirates there, or they were trying to reach a large number of pirates, but I cannot be sure, it has been way too long since seeing the clip. I mostly remember how dark and scary the clip felt and I think at some point the little girl screamed in terror because of the pirates. I do not think this was at all aimed at a child audience, but as this was probably something my parents were watching it is unlikely to be necessarily a complete horror film/show; I may have simply walked in on a 'scary' scene (probably not so scary as an adult).